# fluentd multiline parser in parser filter

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, kubernetes, logging, fluentd

I'm trying to parse multiline logs from my applications in fluentd on kubernetes.

I currently have the following filter *dropped-in* my fluentd container:

```
<filter kubernetes.**>
  @type parser
  key_name log
  emit_invalid_record_to_error false # do not fail on non-matching log messages
  reserve_data true # keep the log key (needed for non-matching records)
  <parse>
    @type multiline
    format_firstline /\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}/
    format1 /^(?<time>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3})\s+(?<level>\S+)(?:\s+\[[^\]]*\])?\s+(?<pid>\d+)\s+---\s+\[\s*(?<thread>[^\]]+)\]\s+(?<class>\S+)\s+:\s+(?<message>.*)/
    time_format %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%L
    types pid:integer
  </parse>
</filter>
```

This filter should parse spring boot style logs (which is not that important, as it is not working for my other filters as well).

Single line logs are parsed fine! All capture groups are detected and time format and pid type is also saved as an integer. But in case of a multi line log statement, the next line is just left as it is and saved as its own entry.

I got the idea for this parser from the fluentd documentation: https://docs.fluentd.org/parser/multiline

The documentation says currently *in_tail plugin works with multiline but other input plugins do not work with it.*

The container I'm using uses the `in_tail` plugin to get the logs. But I'm using the parser inside a filter. Not sure if this might be the problem? In the documentation the *parser filter plugin* (https://docs.fluentd.org/filter/parser) just links to the *Parser Plugin Overview* (https://docs.fluentd.org/parser) without mentioning anything about single parsers not working.

Would be great if someone could point me into the right direction!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I came recently to exactly the same issue and still couldn't find obvious solution so I had to figure it out myself. It is exactly as it is in doc - this parser you mentioned works only as Parser section in Input plugin ('in_tail' only). It doesn't work in filter plugin unfortunately.

But for me this plugin helped:
https://github.com/fluent-plugins-nursery/fluent-plugin-concat

You just have to add one filter section above your main one where you do this concat, e.g. my example looks exactly like this (indicator of real new log is timestamp, if there is no timestamp it is always stacktrace of errors where the problem appears):

```
<filter XYZ.**>
  @type concat
  key log
  multiline_start_regexp /\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}/
</filter>
<filter>
   # here the original filter
</filter>
```

Comment: Yeah, I found something like this as well some time ago. Unfortunately this still has the issue, that it blocks messages in case the stacktrace is the last log message. There are solutions with some timeouts and error handling. It works. But does not seem to be the nicest solution :/

Comment: Hmm actually why timeout is not nice solution ('flush_interval' in this plugin). There is 'multiline_end_regexp' for clean solution BUT if you are not able to specify the end condition and multiline comes from single event (which is probably your case) and there is no new event for some time THEN imho it is the only and clean solution and even robust. If you set timeout=1s does it hurt you that log appears in elastic not 1ms after event but 1s after event? I guess flush interval for fluentd->elastic you have higher, however.

Comment: I find it "not so nice", as the timeout puts the messages in some kind of error state, that you then need to account for (they are by default not handled as all other messages). These additional filters and mappers to handle those messages and put them back to "the normal handling".. this looks and feels like a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

It was pain to find solution for this problem, I hope it will help you guys.
This piece of code works for my logs from spring-boot application, with span and trace id included, saved in JSON format by Docker.

Pattern of logs:

```
<property name="CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN" value="${CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN:-%clr(%d{${LOG_DATEFORMAT_PATTERN:-yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX}}){faint}%clr(${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:-%5p}) %clr(${PID:- }){magenta} %clr(---){faint}%clr([%15.15t]){faint} %clr(%-40.40logger{39}){cyan} %clr(:){faint} %crlf(%m){red} %n${LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD:-%wEx}}"/>
```

Working solution:

```
<source>
  @type tail
  @id in_tail_ms_logs
  @label @ms
  path /var/log/containers/ms-*.log
  pos_file /var/log/ms.log.pos
  tag *
  read_from_head true
  <parse>
    @type json
    time_format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%NZ
  </parse>
</source>
      
<label @ms>
  <filter **>
    @type kubernetes_metadata
    @id filter_kube_metadata_ms
    watch false
  </filter>

  <filter **>
    @type record_transformer
    @id filter_stream_transformer_ms
    <record>
      stream_name ${tag_parts[3]}
    </record>
  </filter>
 
  <filter **>
    @type concat
    key log
    multiline_start_regexp /\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}/
    flush_interval 0
  </filter>
    
  <filter **>
    @type parser
    key_name log
    reserve_time true
    reserve_data true
    inject_key_prefix parser.
    <parse>
      @type regexp
      expression /^(?<date_time>\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}T\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\.\d{1,3}[a-zA-Z]{0,3})[\s]{0,2}(?<level>[^\s]+) \[(?<app_name>[a-zA-Z0-9-_]*),(?<trace_id>[a-zA-Z0-9-_]*),(?<span_id>[a-zA-Z0-9-_]*)\] (?<pid>[a-zA-Z0-9-_]*) --- \[(?<thread>.*)\][\s\S]*/
    </parse>
  </filter>
                
  <match **>
    @type relabel
    @label @NORMAL
  </match>
</label>
```